# How to make object of child type access parent method?

Tags: java

I have the following object of type Superman. I need it to call a method twice, once from the Superman class, and once from ActionCharacter -parent. How to do that?

```
interface CanFight {void fight();}
interface CanFly {void fly();}
interface interface CanClimb{void climb();}
interface CanSwim{
     void swimFast();
     void treadH2O();
}
class ActionCharacter {
     public void fight() {System.out.println("fight an ActionChar");}
}
class Superman extends ActionCharacter implements CanFight, CanFly, CanClimb, CanSwim{
     String name = "Superman";
     public void fight() {System.out.println("fight bad guys");}
     public void fly() {System.out.println("fly faster than a bird");}  
     public void swimFast() {System.out.println("Swim faster than Michael Phelps");}
     public void treadH2O() {System.out.println("Tread water forever");}
     public void climb() {System.out.println("climb vertical cliffs");}
}
public class Action {
     public static void t(CanFight x) { x.fight(); }
     public static void v(CanFly x) { x.fly(); }
     public static void w(ActionCharacter x) { x.fight();}
     public static void x(CanClimb x) {x.climb();}
     public static void y(CanSwim x) {x.swimFast(); x.treadH2O();}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Superman h = new Superman();
    System.out.println("I am " + h.name + " I can do the following:" );
    t(h); // Treat it as a CanFight
    y(h);
    v(h); // Treat it as a CanFly
    x(h);
    w(h); //This should print fight an ActionChar
    ActionCharacter i = (ActionCharacter)h;
    w(i); //Second attempt to print fight an ActionChar
}
}
```

Comment: Use `super.fight()` to call a superclass method.

Comment: In addition to @LppEdd comment, you should read [Using the Keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 0):

define the method in your superclass `ActionCharacter` and override it in your subclass `Superman` , so both objects (type of Superman & type of ActionCharacter) are able to use this method

Comment: I've defined it in ActionCharacter and @Override in Superman. I still get the printout just from Superman.

Answer (score 0):

The **super** keyword in java is a reference variable that is used to refer parent class objects

in the Superman class:

```
fight();
```

To call from ActionCharacter parent:

```
super.fight();
```

[super keyword](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/super-keyword/)

Comment: I have t, v, w, x, y methods that take in objects and call that object of the intended method. Even so, calling 
public static void w(ActionCharacter x) { 
     x.fight();
}
is not printing out the parent's fight().